# App crash (if closed) after click on notification

Tags: android, azure, notifications, push

I've a problem with my application. I use a class to manage push notification from Azure, extending NotificationsHandler.All works,the method onReceive "catch" the incoming notification,using bundle i can read each field of the json from azure server.If i click on the notification i can start the activity as follows:

`fragment_richiesta_tabsV2 dettaglioTabs= new fragment_richiesta_tabsV2();
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(contesto, dettaglioTabs.getClass());
 contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contesto, 0,myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

the problem is when the app is closed from the recent apps.The notification arrives,but if i click on the app crash...how can i solve?
thanks

Comment: If i open the task manager,the app is there,but some parameters are probably null...if i try to open the app,clicking on it,it crash another time...

Comment: Ok i've solved!The debug if i close the app doesn't  works,so i can't see the problem...but finally i've solved.The problem was that some variable were instantiated in other activity that now aren't running,so i've got so many null pointer exception.Now i've solved...